# How to use an iterator pointing to a vector of structs c++?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I need help with my `code`. I don't understand how to use the returned `pointers` to access elements in a struct stored in  a vector :

```
struct receptionEvents
{
    int chFreqIndex; //0
    int chSFIndex; //1
    simtime_t endReceptionTime ;
    double SNR; //2
    bool collidedFlag; //0= false(Not Corrupted) 1=Corrupted
};
  std::vector<receptionEvents> buffRxEvents;
```

Now in main function I am trying to find all structs named `receptionEvents` that match a certain `chFreqIndex` using the below line :

```
int chFreqIndexCheck == 4;
     auto vpit = find_if( buffRxEvents.begin(), buffRxEvents.end(), [&] 
(receptionEvents const & m) { return m.chFreqIndex == chFreqIndexCheck;} );
```

Now my problem is how to use the vpit iterator to iterate over all found entries in my vector and how to access the data variables of each. Can any one help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::find_if` only finds the first occurence. But you could search the next element beginning at the successor of the currently found element, such as:

```
auto vpit = buff.begin();
while(vpit != buff.end())
{
    vpit = std::find_if(vpit, buff.end(), [](/*...*/){ /*...*/ });
    if(vpit != buff.end())
    {
        // use it
        ++vpit; // for not finding current element AGAIN!
    }
}
```

Simpler, though, is a simple range based for loop:

```
for(auto e : buff)
{
     if( /* ... */ )
     { /* ... */ }
}
```

Edit:

> but how exactly can I use it

You can just use it as if it was a pointer: `*vpit` to access the data the iterator "points to", `vpit->x` to access a member of, if data is a complex type (as in your example).

Example:

```
receptionEvents someCopy = *vpit; // copies entire struct
int cfIndex = vpit->chFreqIndex;
```

Comment: okey i am sorry bare with me.I am new to that. but how exactly can I use it, what is the syntax to use that vpit pointer to access the data elements of that struct?

Comment: @MinarEl-Aasser `vpit->collidedFlag` for example

Comment: @Aconcagua thank you now it works, but i think the syntex for this command is wrong?                                                                                                      
          auto vpit = find_if( buffRxEvents.begin(), buffRxEvents.end(), [&]
                   (receptionEvents const & m) { return m.chFreqIndex == 
       chFreqIndexCheck;} );   because it gives wrong answer? I am trying to find the 1st entry with the same chFreqIndex

Comment: @MinarEl-Aasser Syntax is fine, but numbers of parameters is wrong, of course you need to add the lambda. As you already figured out how to call `find_if`, I've been a bit short there...

Comment: thank you so much, your tips helped me solve the issue:)

Answer (score 4):

The [`std::find` family of functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns an iterator to a *single* element (or `end` if nothing is found).

If you want to get *all* elements that matches your condition, then you could use [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy to a new container (possibly with the help of [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)).

You can of course have your own loop, calling `std::find_if` multiple times and pass the previous `vpit` plus one as the beginning of the range you search through.

Or use [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) or a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) with a check for the current element to see if it matches your condition.

Comment: The copying prevents me from upvoting for its inefficiency, on the other side, the last option is what I would opt for... Too bad there is no `std::for_each_if` (yet?)...

Comment: @Aconcagua There are cases where you'd better _copy_ things around to _improve_ performance. Treat your cache well, and it will treat you well. Plus, the question is not about performance.

Comment: @YSC If I re-use the copy as cache for possibly numerous iterations, totally accepted. But this scenario then should be added to the corresponding paragraph in the question as well...

Comment: @YSC If the copy approach was the simplest one to implement and more efficient solutions were far more complex, I'd totally accept your point on performance. But as alternatives are even *less* complex (range based for loop), I think it is just bad advice...